# What does the set R/{0} represent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

It looks like it refers to the set R- {0}, but I looked the question (from where I got it) up on the internet, and it's written the same everywhere. The function in consideration has a term with a zero in the denominator, so I'm pretty sure, but I'd like a confirmation.

Comment: Without more context, we cannot say.  I have seen people write $A / B$ for $A \setminus B$. Sort of like Windows writing $\setminus$ for the Unix $/$.

Comment: "$R$"?  Or "$\Bbb R$"?  "$/$" or "$\setminus$"?  $R/\{0\}$ doesn't make sense to me.  $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ does and is the set of nonzero real numbers.

Comment: Is there actually a difference between the two Rs?

Comment: To some authors?  No.  To other authors?  Possibly.  The authors I studied from very explicitly used $\Bbb{R}$ and only $\Bbb R$ for the set of real numbers and if they used $R$ it was always for a different set or object, such as an arbitrary relation or arbitrary ring.

Comment: As for the direction of the slash, a slash like $/$ could have been in reference to a [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) or similarly quotient ring.  The slash in the other direction, $\$ is what is used for set difference and should not be confused.

Comment: The question says $f: R/{0}-> R, f(x)= \frac{1}{x}- \frac{2}{e^{2x}-1}$. This notation might be important, as the limit as the function approaches x=0 is logically 0, but when I graphed it online, the function approached 1.

Comment: "*As the limit as the function approaches $x=0$ is logically $0$*"  What makes you say that?  You do realize that $\infty - \infty$ is invalid and could have been anything, yes?  As for $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ note that your function is not defined at identically $x=0$ since division by zero is undefined.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R/{0} = R$- \{0\} =$ the set of all $x$ such that $x$ belongs to $R$ and $x$ does not belong to {0} = the set of all $x$ such that x belongs to R and  $x\not = 0$.

---

- $R$ is a set, the set of real numbers.
- If you want $R$ without $0$ in it, you cannot get this new set by writing : $R - 0$. The reason is that :
- (a) If you treat $O$ as a number ( and not a set) the expression does not mean anything ( set operations - here : set difference -  operate only on sets). You cannot " substact" a number from a set.
- (b) If you treat $O$ as a set, namely, as the empty set ( as set theory does) you get :

$R-O = R - \emptyset = $ the set of all $x$ such that (1) $x\in R$ and (2) $x\not\in\emptyset = R$.

Note: condition (2) changes nothing, since any object whatever satisfies it.

- So if you want $R$ without $0$ in it, you have to "substact" , so to say, the singleton set  $\{0\}$ from the set $R$, that is, you need the set difference : $R - \{0\}$.